# Replace line break in email using Replace()

Tags: vba, excel, email, line-breaks

In the process of trying to automate an Outlook Email with VBA through Excel.

Towards the end of my code I have a string of values in an Excel cell separated by `;#` (Example: `;#abacus;#bicycle;#cheese;#`).

Once I get to the .HTMLBody section of the email creation portion, I'm using Replace() to remove the separator.

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ";#", ", ")
```

This is great as it separates the list with a comma. I have another piece that handles the beginning as well (the `;#` before the beginning of my list). This looks for the specific instance of "List: , "

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "List: , ", "List:")
```

Which should now read: "List: abacus, bicycle, cheese, "

I'm attempting to now remove the extra comma and space after the end of my list ("cheese, " should end as "cheese"). List will always have different values with different lengths in it, not necessarily ending in cheese, but always ending in `;#` based on the value separator.

I know the last value always follows with a return `< br >` in the email, but when I try this code, it doesn't work (line breaks have included spaces around brackets to not break code block, they don't in my real VBA code):

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ", < br >< br >", "< br >< br >")
```

Based on my crazy system of replacing values (in this case, aiming to replace three times), I feel like it should work, but it does not.

Is VBA not capable of searching for a string with line breaks in it and replacing it with just line breaks?

I also feel like there is a better way to do this - my VBA is shoddy at best.

Comment: Try .HTMLBody = Left(.HTMLBody, len(.HTMLBody)-2) to get rid of the trailing comma and space.  Not sure I understand the second part of the question.

Comment: `<br>` is a line break in HTML.  But `chr(13)+chr(10)` or `vbCrLf` is how you represent carriage return + line feed in VBA.  Perhaps try those?

Comment: Any chance you can show the entire HTML string (as raw HTML) -- or at least a sample to cover the beginning, end and the area getting modified, both as-is and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD Chris,

It appears you approach the problem in reverse ?
Further, you indicate your start string to be:

```
";#abacus;#bicycle;#cheese;#"
```

Yet you indicate in your second 'Replace' step that there is also a value present "List:" ? This should either be part of the initial string otherwise it cannot be found in the second Replace statement ?

Anyway assuming your initial String is:

```
"List:;#abacus;#bicycle;#cheese;#"
```

Your objective is to manipulate this string to build the .HTMLbody component.

This can be easily done by splitting the string based on the delimiter ";#"

And rebuilding for non-empty strings as per below, where s will be your start string:

```
Function HTMLBody(s As String) As String

    Dim b As String

    s = Replace(s, "List:", vbNullString)   'Removes the "List:" section
    aStr = Split(s, ";#")    'Split the string in an array through the ";#" delimiter

    For Each a In aStr    'Loop through all array values
        If Not a = vbNullString Then   'Test if array value is not empty
            If b = vbNullString Then   'Test if b is 'uninitialised' to allow addition of first item without the ","
                b = a
            Else
                b = b & "," & a
            End If
        End If
    Next

    b = "List:" & b     'Add "List:" back onto the build string

    HTMLBody = b    'Set the HTMLBody() return value

End Function
```

You can then call the "HTMLBody" function by:

```
Sub callHTMLBody()

    .HTMLbody = HTMLBody("List:;#abacus;#bicycle;#cheese;#")

End Sub
```

That should get you the correct String manipulation ?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help mtholen. I wasn't aware of the Split function for delimiters (duh!). Ended up using that piece and your formatting loop for the comma between list items. Greatly appreciate it!